# SQL to join tables only where ALL specified criteria are true

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two tables, 'cars' and 'properties', linked by table 'car_properties'. I can select all cars that have say, electric windows **OR** radios **OR** both, doing something like the following...

```
SELECT cars.id 
FROM cars 
JOIN car_properties 
   ON cars.id = car_properties.car_id 
WHERE 
   car_properties.property_id = 1 
   OR car_properties.property_id = 2
```

where the property_id of 'electric windows' would be '1' and 'car radio' would be '2'.

BUT, what I really want to do is select ONLY cars that have BOTH properties (not just one or the other or both).

I suspect this is really simple, but what's the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Please format your SQL code. Don't just put the whole thing in one long line.

Comment: You will find a plethora of answers for this exact situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879

Comment: Your question suggests that the structure of your car_properties table is car_properties{property_id, value}. If this is the case you would likely find it advisable to redesign this so that each unique attribute (property ID) is a separate column. It will help you avoid situations like this.

Comment: @ObscureRobot Quite right. Sorry.

Comment: @Carth Thanks, but I don't really think that's suitable for my particular app.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter That's exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN twice:

```
SELECT cars.id
  FROM cars
  JOIN car_properties AS cp1
    ON cp1.car_id = cars.id
   AND cp1.property_id = 1
  JOIN car_properties AS cp2
    ON cp2.car_id = cars.id
   AND cp2.property_id = 2
;
```